# Sites like http://learnyouahaskell.com for Ocaml and Erlang

Tags: erlang, ocaml

I'm looking for sites like http://learnyouahaskell.com for learning Ocaml and Erlang. It's much sites and tutorials about Ocaml or Erlang but I can't find any sites like this in link (good interface, much examples, easy for beginners). Thanks for help :)

Comment: You can simply google before posting here.

Comment: I suggest you learn from here: https://realworldocaml.org/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For Erlang: http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content
I don't know any for OCaml.

Comment: LYSEFGG is easily one of the top three recommended books regarding erlang (other two would be "Programming Erlang" and "Erland and OTP in action"). The online content is good, and is the basis for the book, but if you have the means and are serious about learning erlang, get the book ;)

Answer (score 6):

For OCaml, I'd suggest the book *Real World OCaml*. Presently the authors include a link to the [full HTML text](https://realworldocaml.org/v1/en/html/index.html) on their website. It holds your hand a bit less than LYAH with regard to the basic fundamentals of functional programming, but if you're already familiar with Haskell, this might serve you well.

Answer (score 1):

For OCaml you have try.ocamlpro.com.